# When I install a module with NPM that I have forked in git I only get a few of the files, why is that?

Tags: reactjs, git, npm

I have forked and modified the react module "react-sortable-tree" in Git.
Here is my fork...

When I do `npm install https://github.com/react-sortable-tree.git` npm only pulls in the changelog.md, package.json, readme.md and licence. I understand that I need to build this but it is impossible to build it without the rest of the files. Why is NPM not getting all of the files?

Comment: Presumably because the source code in GitHub and what gets deployed via NPM is *not the same code*. This is very common with code that's transpiled from newer ES versions or TS. Look in the package file - the app is built before it's published, and the files that are included in the package aren't all included in the repo.

Comment: No because I am the person who wrote that and I am still none the wiser

Comment: Sorry; the canned message isn't very useful in these cases. The point is to not ask the same question again; [edit], instead.

Comment: What is a canned message?

Comment: The message that's automatically generated by the system, in this case when casting a vote to close as a duplicate. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canned_response

Answer (score 0):

you should be doing the following instead:

```
git clone https://github.com/lewishornsby/react-sortable-tree.git
```

then go into the directory `react-sortable-tree`, then do:

```
npm install
```

The install will get all of the files / dependencies needed by the project. After that look inside the `scripts` section of the `package.json` file or read the `README` file to see how to build the project.

Comment: Thanks so much! It worked but has installed it outside of the node_modules directory, is this normal? I have managed to build it successfully but am worried it's gone somewhere it should not have gone.

Comment: @Lewis don't worry. You shouldn't even _have_ a node_modules directory until AFTER you perform the steps outlined above. `npm install` creates the node_modules folder. I think you'll be alright! good luck! :)